# Mvc action link redirect to folder within view folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following folder structure

```
->People
-->Views
--->Reports
--->index.cshtml
---->PhoneCalls
----->Report.cshtml
-->Controlers
--->ReportsControler.cs
```

how do I navigate from index.cshtml to Report.cshtml using a `@html.ActionLink` helper

I have tried

```
@Html.ActionLink("Report", "PhoneCalls/Report", null, new { target = "__blank" });
```

with fail.

Comment: ActionLinks do not link to views, they link to controller actions. What controller action returns the view "PhoneCalls/Report"?

Comment: Updated the folder structure in question to include the controller folder and the controller action is Report in the ReportController.cs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure what your setup is, but for the general case of linking to a view that is included in a subfolder of the `Views` folder.

Link to your controller action that handles the view, not the view itself

```
@Html.ActionLink("Report", "Report", "Reports", null, new { target = "_blank" });
```

First parameter is just the link text, followed by the action, then the controller (not the view), no route parameters, and your HTML attributes.

The `Report` action on the `Reports` controller is going to look for a `Views/Reports/Report.cshtml` file. Since this does not exist, you can pass in a string parameter to the `View()` method to specify which view you're actually using.

```
public ActionResult Report()
{
  // Do your controller work

  return View("PhoneCalls/Report");
}
```

Comment: This will work, but you are making assumptions about the ViewEngine being used. I would recommend just putting the "shared" view in the shared folder.

Comment: @KhalidAbuhakmeh, In the question he uses Razor syntax with .cshtml files, so I'm not sure that is an assumption. Unless you meant something else?

Comment: yes, people can clear the default ViewEngines in ASP.Net MVC and have a different search structure. The only reason the addition of "/" works is because the default view engines use string concatenation. So this answer depends on the default view engines being in place. This is still a good answer, just will not work in every situation, especially for people getting fancy :).